# How can you prove the Nested Interval(s) Theorem in $\mathbb R$ without reference to the least upper bound property?

Tags: real-analysis, alternative-proof

Claim: a nested sequence of closed bounded intervals in $\mathbb R$ has nonempty intersection.

A textbook provides a proof using the least upper bound property of the real numbers, but adds an aside that the theorem can be proved in $\mathbb R$ in alternate ways. I'm hoping for some examples of proofs that do not use the least upper bound property.

Comment: If the least upper bound property appears in the definition of ${\mathbb R}$ you can't do without it. So what is your model of the reals? (Dedekind cuts, Cauchy sequences, decimal expansions, etc.)

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Interestingly the text first defines the reals as an ordered field with lub, then proves that any two ordered fields with lub are order isomorphic, then proves NIT, THEN reconstructs the reals as equiv. classes of Cauchy seqs, eventually proves that lub property holds for this set, and remarks that these constructed reals are order isomorphic to the earlier ones. Much later, the text proves the analogous result for nested compact sets in metric spaces, but the phrasing of the remark about other proofs suggested that it was not that later proof that the author was thinking of.

Comment: Note that a similar result holds in every complete metric space and is false for general metric spaces, so it will have to rely somehow on the completeness of $\mathbb R$, which is equivalent to the lub property of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: More concretely: this property fails to hold for $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @AlexanderThumm Hence my curiosity about the author's remark! His exact words were "There is often some confusion about the relationship between the Nested Intervals Theorem in $\mathbb R$ and the least upper bound property. Although our proof in $\mathbb R$ involves the least upper bound property, it can be proved in other ways." Based on your remark, would you conclude that when the author says "other ways," he must mean "superficially different" but actually equivalent ways? I was inclined to think he meant there were actually substantively different proofs...again, hence my curiosity.

Comment: @Philip: the proof using continuity looks different at first sight and is probably what the author had in mind. Examining it a little bit more closely reveals, that those two proofs are essentially the same.

Comment: My guess is that the author was referring the more general case that in a compact space if a family of closed sets has the finite intersection property, then it has a nonempty intersection.

Comment: @AlexanderThumm Which proof using continuity did you have in mind?

Comment: I meant completeness. The related theorem sais: Let $(F,d)$ be a complete metric space and $A_1, A_2, \dots$ be a sequence of nested closed subsets of $F$, that is $F \supset A_1 \supset A_2 \supset \dots$ such that the diameters $\text{diam}(A_n) = \sup_{x,y \in A_n}d(x,y) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, then $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N} A_n \not = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a sense in which the LUB property and NIT property
are mathematically equivalent for the purpose arising in
your context. This theorem provides a sense (namely,
separable linear orders) in which it isn't possible to
prove the NIT in a context where LUB fails; they arrive
together. Thus, the question is one of presentation rather
than mathematical possibility.

**Theorem.** Suppose that $\langle R,\lt\rangle$ is any
linear order with a countable dense set. Then it satisfies
the LUB property if and only if it satisfies the NIT
property.

Proof. Suppose it satisfies the LUB property, and
$[a_0,b_0]\supset [a_1,b_1]\supset\cdots$ is a descending
sequence of intervals. It follows easily that the least
upper bound of the $a_n$ is in every interval, and so the
NIT property holds. Conversely, suppose that the NIT
property holds and that $A\subset R$ is nonempty and
bounded above. Enumerate the countable dense set
$Q=\{q_n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, and define a sequence of
intervals $[a_n,b_n]$ as follows. The intervals will zero in on where we expect to find the lub of $A$. Choose any $a_0\in A$ and
any upper bound $b_0$ of $A$ in $R$. If $[a_n,b_n]$ has
been defined, then consider $q_n$. We keep the same
interval, unless $a_n\lt q_n\lt b_n$. In this case, we shrink the interval so as to decide $q_n$. That is, if $A$
has elements from the top half $[q_n,b_n]$, then we shrink
the interval on that side with
$[a_{n+1},b_{n+1}]=[q_n,b_n]$, and otherwise we shrink the
interval towards the other side with
$[a_{n+1},b_{n+1}]=[a_n,q_n]$. One can now easily prove
that $A$ has elements from every interval, that $A$ is
bounded above by every $b_n$, that there is a unique
element in the intersection of the intervals, and that this
element is the least upper bound of $A$. QED

Things become interesting when one drops the
countable-dense-set hypothesis. As the argument shows, the
LUB property still implies the NIT property in any linear
order, but the converse can fail. One easy (counter)example
is the order $\mathbb{R}^\ell\oplus\mathbb{R}$, that is,
the [long
line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_%28topology%29)
$\mathbb{R}^\ell$ with a copy of the reals on top; the order
$\omega_1+\omega^\ast$ works just as well. These orders
have the NIT, because any countable sequence of intervals
that eventually stays on one side of the principal cut will
be fine, and those that straddle the cut will have the left
hand sides bounded in $\mathbb{R}^\ell$, since every
countable subset of the long line is bounded, and hence
have nonempty intersection. But the order does not have the
LUB property because of the principal cut between the two
orders.

One might be tempted to extend the NIT to longer
transfinite nested sequences of intervals, but actually
these two orders continue to have the NIT property even for
such longer transfinite sequences. This is because of the
mis-match in cofinality between the lower and upper sides
of the principal cut. If the length of a sequence of
intervals straddling this cut has countable cofinality,
then it will be bounded in the lower part, and if it has
uncountable cofinality, then it will be eventually constant
in the upper part; so in any case, sequences of nested
closed intervals of any transfinite length will have a
nonempty intersection, but the LUB property fails.

The resolution is not to use sequences, but to use filters
(or nets), and this is a standard idea in topology when one
gets away from the separable case.
A linear order has the LUB property if and only if every filter of closed intervals has nonempty intersection. The forward direction is similar to the above, and for the reverse, consider the collection of intervals that straddle where you think the LUB of a set $A$ should be, and the unique point in the intersection of them will be the LUB of $A$.

Comment: Joel, what is the proper generalization for $R$ with a $\kappa$-dense subset? (Is it some form of $\kappa$-Lindolef-ness or so?)

Comment: I edited to explain one such generalization, but it depends on which part you want to generalize.

Comment: @JDH Thanks for this detail. In light of your helpful remarks, do you have any idea what the author might have meant when he said "it can be proved in other ways"?

Comment: I suspect he meant only that one can present a proof that does not explicitly mention the LUB property. For example, you could pove it using the compactness of intervals, or the GLB property, etc., although the larger point remains that all these properties are equivalent in a general sense. For example, I guess one can prove LUB from Rolle's theorem, if you really want to give a crazy order, by considering a certain signed distance function.

Comment: Joel, thanks for the further explanation!

Comment: @JDH Thanks again. Your answer is on my to-accept list, as I expected to receive several answers each with different proofs but yours essentially argues that none such are possible. I'm going to try to contact the author and will report back here / probably accept your answer depending on whether and how he responds.

Comment: I'd be interested to hear the reply.

Answer (score 6):

As Yuval Filmus says in the comments, an important basic observation is that a nested collection of closed bounded intervals in $\mathbb{Q}$ may have empty intersection. Thus any proof of this property must make use of a property of $\mathbb{R}$ which is not a property of $\mathbb{Q}$. The least upper bound property is one of the most important such properties, and there are others, many of which turn out to be equivalent (in an appropriate sense) to the least upper bound property.